# why do you have {} around variables in a sql statement?

Tags: sql

why do you use {} around variables in following sql statement?

```
SELECT
FROM users
WHERE username = '{$_POST['user']}'
```

Comment: Which SQL dialect are you using?

Comment: This looks like a parameter (the field user coming in from a web form) in PHP?   Somewhere in the code, the parameter gets updated, because the above syntax is not likely to run in SQL

Comment: Looks like Perl or PHP...don't know enough Ruby.  Could also be for a stored procedure in some dialect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume you are using SQL from within PHP language.

This syntax with `{}` is used to interpolate array elements embedded in quoted string.

For example, composing the following string:

```
"Good morning {$_POST['user']} !"
```

will compile output with the value of variable (array element) dereferenced, for instance:

```
"Good morning noname !"
```

SQL queries in PHP are composed from strings, so this `{}` syntax is used fairly often.

Reference: [Variable parsing - complex syntax PHP4+](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

p.s. It's always a good idea to provide as many details as possible in your question.

Comment: but cant u just type echo "Good morning $_POST['user'] !". i think i have tried that before.

Comment: Yes, you can NOT do that. That's why the extra {} are required. Check the Variable parsing section in the reference I linked from my answer. You will find explanation of so called complex syntax with some examples. Simply, use braces to eliminate any potential ambiguity during parsing variables embedded in strings.

Comment: you can with the double quotes, but not with the single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

you can with the double quotes, but not with the single quotes. the question uses single quotes, so i am not so sure it is in PHP. (mabee it was misstyped for the question)

so

```
if $_POST['user'] = "fred";

"Good morning {$_POST['user']} !"
```

translates as
Good morning fred !

but

```
'Good morning {$_POST['user']} !'
```

translates as
Good morning {$_POST['user']} !